# Why isn't this Jquery Valid?

Tags: jquery

I have gone over this for too long without any results, why isn't this jquery working? I am trying to hide the "bid" div as an indicator of the functioning script, but alas, I cannot figure it out. thanks a million for your help

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bid').hide();
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contactform.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function () {
                $('#form').hide();
                $('#messager').fadeIn();
            };
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You could just `.serialize()` your entire form instead of building the query string yourself. It's likely your self-built query string isn't escaped properly (spaces -> %20, things like that). http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: return false; is not needed and may be the error

Comment: test in google chrome, it has a javascript debugger.

Comment: @Patrick first comment; the return is inside the `function` for `.click`, so it shouldn't be causing any problems there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
success: $(function() {
     $('#form').hide();  
    $('#messager').fadeIn();
});
```

To

```
success: function() {
     $('#form').hide();  
    $('#messager').fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, but that's what it looked like in my first iteration, and it didn't work then. Tried it again and still doesn't work

Comment: Can you post it on http://jsfiddle.net please, with the HTML? The code is fine, so there's a problem somewhere else :)

Comment: If the code was fine my "bid" div would be hidden, and it isn't

Comment: Let me rephrase; The code I posted should work :) Because it doesn't, can you post what you have right now, and we'll troubleshoot that to give you something that will definitely work?

Comment: You told me my code didn't work :P You have a trailing semicolon after the `success: function() { } ;` which is breaking it. Change that to `success: function() { }` and it will work.

Comment: My Bust Joe, thanks a million, I didn't think that semicolon did anything! You're the man

Comment: If you look at it another way, you're still inside the { } of the JSON object there, and a semicolon is illegal. If you had something after the `success` option, you'd need a comma if anything (but don't leave a trailing comma of death! http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/)

Answer (score 1):

You had a syntax error in the ajax block, should be:

```
$.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "contactform.php",  
      data: dataString,  
       success: function() {
         $('#form').hide();  
        $('#messager').fadeIn();
            }  
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted code from after fooling with it in every which way, that is how it looked originally and it didn't work, tried it again and still doesn't work